# syntax error in sql query?

Tags: sqlite, syntax, syntax-error, create-table

I want to create some tables in database so for that i wright some queries to create table.
but i got an error "there was a syntax error in your sql statement". I check all my queries but i am not able to find what syntax i wright wrong. here i attached my sql queries please told me what is wrong with queries.
Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TABLE "WATER&SEWAGE" (
 "CUSTOMER_ID" VARCHAR,
 "POTABLE_WATER" VARCHAR,
 "HOT_WATER" VARCHAR,
 "SAFETY" VARCHAR,
 "T/P_VALVE+EXT" VARCHAR,
 "HEATER_TYPE" VARCHAR,
 "GAS_VENT_CONDITION" VARCHAR,
 "FIRE_BOX_CONDITION" VARCHAR,
 "PRESSURE" VARCHAR,
 "BACK_FLOW" VARCHAR,
  "PLUMBING_CONDITION" VARCHAR,
  "CABINET_CONDITION" VARCHAR,
  "3_COMP_SINK" VARCHAR,
  "WATER_HEATER" VARCHAR,
  "CLEAN_OUT_CONDITION" VARCHAR,
  "FLOOR_DRAIN" VARCHAR,
  "FLOOR_SINK" VARCHAR,
  "MAINTANANCE" VARCHAR,
  "COMMENTS" VARCHAR,
  "EVIDENCE_PHOTOS" VARCHAR)

CREATE TABLE "TIME_AND_TETMPERATURE_REL" ("CUSTOMER_ID" INTEGER, "THERMOMTE_AVAILABLE" VARCHAR, "THERMO_TYPE" VARCHAR, "COLD_TEMP" VARCHAR, "FOOD_TYPE1" VARCHAR, "PROPER_COOLING" VARCHAR, "FOOD_TYPE2" VARCHAR, "COMPLIANCE" VARCHAR, "FOOD_TYPE3" VARCHAR, "TPHC" VARCHAR, "HACCP" VARCHAR, "HOT_HOLDING_TEMP" VARCHAR, "FOOD_TYPE4" VARCHAR, "HOT_TEMP" VARCHAR, "FOOD_TYPE5" VARCHAR, "IMPROPER_REHEATING" VARCHAR, "FOOD_TYPE6" VARCHAR, "FOOD_OUT_OF_TEMP" VARCHAR, "WRITTEN_PLAN_FILES" VARCHAR, "EMPLOYEE_KNOWLEDGE" VARCHAR, "TIME_KEEPING_METHODS" VARCHAR, "HACCP_METHODS" VARCHAR, "CALIBRATION" VARCHAR, "COOKING_TEMP" VARCHAR, "EQUIP_CONDITION" VARCHAR, "COMMENTS" VARCHAR, "EVIDENCE_PHOTOS" VARCHAR)

CREATE TABLE "PROTECTION_FROM_CONTAMINATION" ("FOOD_ADULTERATION" VARCHAR, "FOOD_SPOILAGE" VARCHAR, "CONTAMINATION" VARCHAR, "FOOD_STORAGE" VARCHAR, "REFRIGRATORS" VARCHAR, "FREEZER" VARCHAR, "FIFO" VARCHAR, "DRY" VARCHAR, "DISHWASHING_CHEMICALS" VARCHAR, "CLEANING" VARCHAR, "SANITIZER" VARCHAR, "SUPPLY_EQUIPMENT" VARCHAR, "PESTICIDES" VARCHAR, "COMMENTS" VARCHAR, "EVIDENCE_PHOTOS" VARCHAR, "CUSTOMER_ID" INTEGER)


CREATE TABLE "PHYSICAL_FACILITIES_2" ("CUSTOMER_ID" VARCHAR, "CEILING" VARCHAR, "WINDOWS" VARCHAR, "SPOILS_STORAGE" VARCHAR, "DOORS" VARCHAR, "PERSONAL_LOCKERS" VARCHAR, "FLOORS" VARCHAR, "CONDITION" VARCHAR, "HANDICAP" VARCHAR, "SELF_CLOSING_ROOM" VARCHAR, "TOILETS" VARCHAR, "TOILET_PAPER" VARCHAR, "TOILET_CONDITION" VARCHAR, "VENTILATION_CONDITION" VARCHAR, "MENS" VARCHAR, "MEN'S_VENTILATION" VARCHAR, "MEN'S_FLOOR_DRAWN" VARCHAR, "MEN'S_TOILET_STALLS" VARCHAR, "MEN'S_HAND_SINK" VARCHAR, "MEN'S_TOWELS" VARCHAR, "WOMEN'S" VARCHAR, "WOMEN'S_VENTILATION" VARCHAR, "WOMEN'S_FLOOR_DRAWN" VARCHAR, "WOMEN'S_TOILET_STALLS" VARCHAR, "WOMEN'S_HAND_SINK" VARCHAR, "WOMEN'S_TOWELS" VARCHAR, "COMMENTS" VARCHAR, "EVIDENCE_PHOTOS" VARCHAR)

CREATE TABLE "PHYSICAL_FACILITIES_1" ("CUSTOMER_ID" VARCHAR, "LIGHTNING" VARCHAR, "KITCHEN" VARCHAR, "STORAGE" VARCHAR, "REFRIGRATION" VARCHAR, "JANITORIAL" VARCHAR, "INTERIOR" VARCHAR, "FIXTURE" VARCHAR, "FOOTCANDLES_1" VARCHAR, "FOOTCANDLES_2" VARCHAR, "FOOTCANDLES_3" VARCHAR, "FOOTCANDLES_4" VARCHAR, "FOOTCANDLES_5" VARCHAR, "EXTERIOR" VARCHAR, "WINDOWS" VARCHAR, "GLASS" VARCHAR, "SCREEN" VARCHAR, "COMMENTS" VARCHAR, "EVIDENCE_PHOTOS" VARCHAR)

CREATE TABLE "PEST_CONTROL" ("CUSTOMER_ID" VARCHAR, "WALL/CEILING_PIPES" VARCHAR, "SANITATION" VARCHAR, "DOORS" VARCHAR, "SELF_CLOSING" VARCHAR, "RODENT_PROOF" VARCHAR, "VERMIN_PROOFING" VARCHAR, "FOUNDATION" VARCHAR, "ATTIC_VENTS" VARCHAR, "WINDOWS" VARCHAR, "TYPE_SCREENS" VARCHAR, "COMMENTS" VARCHAR, "EVIDENCE_PHOTOS" VARCHAR)

CREATE TABLE "GENERAL_FOOD_SAFETY_REQ" ("CUSTOMER_ID" VARCHAR, "APPROVED_METHODS" VARCHAR, "DEFROST" VARCHAR, "FROZEN_FOOD" VARCHAR, "FOOD_WASHING" VARCHAR, "PRODUCE_1" VARCHAR, "FRUITS" VARCHAR, "GRAINS" VARCHAR, "VEGETABLES" VARCHAR, "SEPERATE_FROM_CONT" VARCHAR, "RAW" VARCHAR, "PRODUCE_2" VARCHAR, "STORED_BULK" VARCHAR, "STORAGE" VARCHAR, "FIFO" VARCHAR, "REFRIGRATAION" VARCHAR, "STORAGE_TEMP" VARCHAR, "HUMIDITY" VARCHAR, "COMMENTS" VARCHAR, "EVIDENCE_PHOTOS" VARCHAR)

CREATE TABLE "FOOD_SAFETY_CERTIFICATION" ("CUSTOMER_ID" INTEGER,"OWNER" VARCHAR,"MANAGER" VARCHAR,"EMPLOYEE" VARCHAR,"NAME1" VARCHAR,"NAT'L_REGISTRY1" VARCHAR,"PROMETRIC1" VARCHAR,"SERVESAFE1" VARCHAR,"EXPIRATION1" VARCHAR,"NAME2" VARCHAR,"NAT'L_REGISTRY2" VARCHAR,"PROMETRIC2" VARCHAR,"SERVESAFE2" VARCHAR,"EXPIRATION2" VARCHAR,"COMMENTS" VARCHAR,"FOOD_TEMP" VARCHAR,"DISHWASHER" VARCHAR,"DANGER_ZONE" VARCHAR,"COOLING_FOODS" VARCHAR,"THAWING" VARCHAR,"REHEATING" VARCHAR,"THERMOMETERS" VARCHAR,"FIFO" VARCHAR,"HANDWASH" VARCHAR,"COOKING_TEMP" VARCHAR,"FOOD_POISONING_TYPES" VARCHAR,"EVEDENCE_PHOTOS" VARCHAR)

CREATE TABLE "FOOD_FROM_APPROVED_SOURCES" ("CUSTOMER_ID" VARCHAR, "RECEIPTS" VARCHAR, "DELIVERY_DOOR" VARCHAR, "AIR_CURTAIN" VARCHAR, "VELOCITY" VARCHAR, "OFF_LOAD" VARCHAR, "INSPECTS" VARCHAR, "RODENTS" VARCHAR, "WARNING" VARCHAR, "SHELL_FISH" VARCHAR, "GULF_OYSTER" VARCHAR, "FOOD_OUT_OF_TEMP" VARCHAR, "COMMENTS" VARCHAR, "EVIDENCE_PHOTO" VARCHAR)

CREATE TABLE "FOOD_FACILITY_SITE_FACTS" ("CUSTOMER_ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE,"DBA" VARCHAR,"DISTRICT" VARCHAR,"CITY" VARCHAR,"ZIPCODE" VARCHAR,"ADDRESS" VARCHAR,"SEAT_NO" VARCHAR,"PHONE_NO" VARCHAR,"OWNER" VARCHAR,"PERSON_IN_CHARGE" VARCHAR,"WEBSITE" VARCHAR,"EMAIL" VARCHAR,"FACILITY_TYPE" VARCHAR,"SQ_FOOTAGE" VARCHAR,"NO_OF_SEATS" VARCHAR,"ALCOHOL_SALES" VARCHAR,"LTD_PREP" VARCHAR,"BUSINESS_LICENCE_NO" VARCHAR,"EXPIRATION" VARCHAR,"COMMENTS" VARCHAR,"EVIDENCE_PHOTOS" VARCHAR)

CREATE TABLE "FOOD_DISPLAY_SELF_SERVICE" ("CUSTOMER_ID" VARCHAR, "SELF_SERVICE" VARCHAR, "LIDS" VARCHAR, "UTENSILS" VARCHAR, "HOW_OFTEN_CHANGED" VARCHAR, "SCOOP" VARCHAR, "SNEEZ_GUARD" VARCHAR, "DISHES" VARCHAR, "CROSS" VARCHAR, "SENITATION" VARCHAR, "MAINTANANCE" VARCHAR, "MECHANICAL_CONDITION" VARCHAR, "SERVICE_OF_UTENSIL" VARCHAR, "TIME" VARCHAR, "PRPER_FOOD_LABELING" VARCHAR, "COMMENTS" VARCHAR, "EVIDENCE_PHOTOS" VARCHAR)

CREATE TABLE "EQUIPMENT/UTENSILS/LINES" ("CUSTOMER_ID" VARCHAR, "STORED_DISHES" VARCHAR, "CUPS" VARCHAR, "DAMAGED_DISHES" VARCHAR, "UTENSILS" VARCHAR, "LINES" VARCHAR, "COOLING_EQUIPMENT" VARCHAR, "COOK_WARE_STORAGE" VARCHAR, "CONDITION" VARCHAR, "STORAGE_LOCATION" VARCHAR, "NAPKINS" VARCHAR, "SANITATION" VARCHAR, "ADEQUATE_CAPACITY" VARCHAR, "HAZARDS" VARCHAR, "COMMENTS" VARCHAR, "EVIDENCE_PHOTOS" VARCHAR)

CREATE TABLE "EMPLOYEE_HEALTH_AND_HYGENE" ("CSTOMER_ID" INTEGER, "COMUNICABLE_DIESEASE" VARCHAR, "WIPING_BAGS" VARCHAR, "DISCHARGE" VARCHAR, "LOCKERS" VARCHAR, "PROPER_HAND_WASH" VARCHAR, "RESTROOM_CONDITION" VARCHAR, "HANDWASH_STATION" VARCHAR, "HAIR_RESTRAINT" VARCHAR, "GLOVES_USED" VARCHAR, "WOUND_CARE" VARCHAR, "FOOD_SAMPLE_TESTING" VARCHAR, "GARMENT_CONDITION" VARCHAR, "HEALTH" VARCHAR, "COMMENTS" VARCHAR, "EVIDENCE_PHOTOS" VARCHAR)

CREATE TABLE "DISH&WARE_WASHING" ("CUSTOMER_ID" INTEGER, "TYPE_OF_COMPARTMENT_SINK" VARCHAR, "PLUMBING_ISSUE1" VARCHAR, "QUATERNARY_AMMONIA" VARCHAR, "IODINE" VARCHAR, "HOT_WTR_SANIT_TEMP" VARCHAR, "PLUMBING_ISSUE2" VARCHAR, "HOT_WATER" VARCHAR, "TEMP" VARCHAR, "DISHWASHER_TYPE" VARCHAR, "WAQLL_CONDITION" VARCHAR, "SANITIZER_LEVELS" VARCHAR, "CHLORINE" VARCHAR, "SINK_OR_DISHWASHER" VARCHAR, "EVIDENCE_PHOTOS" VARCHAR)

CREATE TABLE "CORRECTIVE_ACTIONS" ("CUSTOMER_ID" VARCHAR, "CORRECTIVE_ACTIONS" VARCHAR)

CREATE TABLE "CONSUMER_ADVISORY" ("CUSTOMER_ID" VARCHAR, "TRUTH_IN_MENU" VARCHAR, "MAJOR_CHAIN" VARCHAR, "TRANS_FAT" VARCHAR, "SCHOOL" VARCHAR, "PROHIBITED" VARCHAR, "CALORIES" VARCHAR, "COMMENTS" VARCHAR, "EVEDINCE_PHOTOS" VARCHAR)

CREATE TABLE "COMPLAINS&ENFORCEMENTS" ("CUSTOMER_ID" VARCHAR, "PLAN_SUBMITTED" VARCHAR, "APPROVEL" VARCHAR, "CERTIFICATE_OF_OCCU" VARCHAR, "PRIOR_INSPEK_REPORT" VARCHAR, "LAST_INSPECTION_DATE" VARCHAR, "PERMIT_STATUS" VARCHAR, "POSTED" VARCHAR, "EXPIRATION" VARCHAR, "PERMIT_DISPLAYED" VARCHAR, "INSPECTION_REPORT_POSTING" VARCHAR, "COMMENTS" VARCHAR, "EVIDENCE_PHOTOS" VARCHAR)
```

Comment: Woah. Can we have just one example please?

Comment: Did you try formatting the code? Please go through FAQs before proceeding further. SQL is not same as SQLite

Comment: Can you even have `&` in a table name? That doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Are you feeding that whole thing to SQLite without any semicolons?

Comment: @GregHewgill: Sure, that'll work as long as the table name is double-quoted every time it is used. I wouldn't recommend it though.

Comment: Please edit to format code properly. I got you pretty much started on the first table definition; you need to do the rest of them, and then identify the **specific** part of all those statements that is causing the problem (the exact line that's causing the syntax error and the exact message you're getting about the error).

Comment: @mu is too short: i tried as you told "without any semicolons" but it is not working. thanks

Comment: You need semicolons. And the specific error message would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that I saw. The biggest issue appears to be the lack of semicolons. Whenever creating a table - or any sql statement at that - there needs to be a semicolon at the end.

Also, a few suggestions. When declaring variable types, it is usually good practice to limit the length. For instance, instead of VARCHAR, use VARCHAR(20) perhaps. At the same time, add some primary keys and foreign keys for better relations and future queries.

As an example:

```
CREATE TABLE "WATER&SEWAGE" (
"CUSTOMER_ID" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
"POTABLE_WATER" VARCHAR(20),
 PRIMARY KEY('CUSTOMER_ID')) ENGINE InnoDB;
```

While I was writing that, I figured I use InnoDB because it looks like your database is going to be largely transaction based. It might be worthwhile to use InnoDB instead of the standard MyISAM.

In most applications, your database is the foundation of the entire site. It is worthwhile to spend a good amount of time on it to get it right the first time. Plus, when entering the tables, it might be a good idea to do one at a time until the quirks are worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Add semicolons: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/5f70c

Comment: Not an answer. This is a comment to the original question instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should use SQLLite syntax. Currently you are using sql syntax. Please check documentation for SQLLite query syntax.